# Flutter can not play more than 3 video in video player

Tags: android, video, flutter, dart

I create a widget that play videos and in controller put video file and video network but when play 3 videos, I get this error

```
Playback error.
E/ExoPlayerImplInternal(24720): com.google.android.exoplayer2.ExoPlaybackException
E/ExoPlayerImplInternal(24720):     at    com.google.android.exoplayer2.mediacodec.MediaCodecRenderer.throwDecoderInitError(MediaCodecRenderer.jav  a:441)
 E/ExoPlayerImplInternal(24720):    at    com.google.android.exoplayer2.mediacodec.MediaCodecRenderer.maybeInitCodec(MediaCodecRenderer.java:428)
E/ExoPlayerImplInternal(24720):     at com.google.android.exoplayer2.mediacodec.MediaCodecRenderer.onInputFormatChanged(MediaCodecRenderer.java:920)
E/ExoPlayerImplInternal(24720):     at com.google.android.exoplayer2.video.MediaCodecVideoRenderer.onInputFormatChanged(MediaCodecVideoRenderer.java:503)
E/ExoPlayerImplInternal(24720):     at com.google.android.exoplayer2.mediacodec.MediaCodecRenderer.render(MediaCodecRenderer.java:557)
E/ExoPlayerImplInternal(24720):     at com.google.android.exoplayer2.ExoPlayerImplInternal.doSomeWork(ExoPlayerImplInternal.java:518)
E/ExoPlayerImplInternal(24720):     at com.google.android.exoplayer2.ExoPlayerImplInternal.handleMessage(ExoPlayerImplInternal.java:301)
E/ExoPlayerImplInternal(24720):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:98)
E/ExoPlayerImplInternal(24720):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:154)
E/ExoPlayerImplInternal(24720):     at android.os.HandlerThread.run(HandlerThread.java:61)
E/ExoPlayerImplInternal(24720): Caused by: com.google.android.exoplayer2.mediacodec.MediaCodecRenderer$DecoderInitializationException: Decoder init failed: OMX.qcom.video.decoder.avc, Format(1, null, video/avc, -1, null, [1280, 720, -1.0], [-1, -1])
E/ExoPlayerImplInternal(24720):     ... 9 more
E/ExoPlayerImplInternal(24720): Caused by: android.media.MediaCodec$CodecException: Error 0xffffec77
E/ExoPlayerImplInternal(24720):     at android.media.MediaCodec.native_configure(Native Method)
E/ExoPlayerImplInternal(24720):     at android.media.MediaCodec.configure(MediaCodec.java:1884)
E/ExoPlayerImplInternal(24720):     at com.google.android.exoplayer2.video.MediaCodecVideoRenderer.configureCodec(MediaCodecVideoRenderer.java:450)
E/ExoPlayerImplInternal(24720):     at com.google.android.exoplayer2.mediacodec.MediaCodecRenderer.maybeInitCodec(MediaCodecRenderer.java:418)
E/ExoPlayerImplInternal(24720):     ... 8 more
```

This is my widget that use it in other pages

```
ChewieDemoState(this.url);
VideoPlayerController _controller;

@override
void initState() {
super.initState();
final path =Provider.of<DirectoryPath>(context,listen:false).directory;

_controller = new File("$path/${url.split('/').last.replaceAll("%20", "_")}").existsSync()?
VideoPlayerController.file(new File("$path/${url.split('/').last.replaceAll("%20", "_")}")):
VideoPlayerController.network(url);

}
@override
void dispose() {
_controller.dispose();
super.dispose();

  }
  @override
 Widget build(BuildContext context) {
 return  new Center(
            child: new Chewie(
              _controller,
              aspectRatio: 3 / 2,
              autoPlay: true,
              looping: true,

              // Try playing around with some of these other options:

              // showControls: false,
               materialProgressColors: new ChewieProgressColors(
                 playedColor: Colors.blue,

                 handleColor: Colors.blue,
                 backgroundColor: Color(0xFF282828),
                 bufferedColor: Colors.lightGreen,
               ),
               placeholder: new Container(
                 color:  Color(0xFF282828),
               ),
              // autoInitialize: true,
            ),
          );
  }
}
```

how to fix this error what i get this error after three video attemp i give video file and video network to it what i use of dispose method correctly?
three video played but more than not i use chewie package

Comment: Small devices like phones are not capable of playing more that a couple videos simultaneously. Decoding video takes hardware resources that become exhausted.

Comment: how to fix it i need code

Comment: can't fix, no code

Comment: @mohammadshabani did you solve your problem? I have the same error and I can't find out a solution. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 4):

Its a bit late but here is the solution. I pulled so many hairs to finally conclude this.

The "video_player" library from "pub.dev" doesn't manage the resources as we expected.

If you initialize a new video without disposing the controller itself it allocates new resources and if you continue to initialize more than 3 videos, phone's platform specific player in this case the "exoplayer2" fails to log out the correct error message

Make sure the controller is disposed and a new one created every time you play a different video.

**Edit:**

```dart
Future<void> playVideo() async{
    VideoPlayerController _old = videoPlayerController;
    if(mounted)
      setState(() {
        videoPlayerController = null;
      });
    videoPlayerController = VideoPlayerController.file(widget.videoFiles[itemIndex]);
    await videoPlayerController.initialize();
    if(mounted)
      setState(() {duration = videoPlayerController.value.duration;});
    await videoPlayerController.play();
    Future.delayed(Duration(seconds: 1),(){
      _old?.dispose();
    });
  }
```

Comment: If it's disposed and new one created, it throws this error -> Unhandled Exception: A VideoPlayerController was used after being disposed.

Comment: any solution of this issue, i am getting the same. https://forums.plex.tv/t/com-google-android-exoplayer-a-i-audiotrack-init-failed/144229

Comment: @reverie_ss first, stop the video and make sure contoller is not accessed by any function or player then dispose the controller and create a new one and update the state to let the new controller to attach itself to the player widget

Answer (score 0):

Use below frame width & height.
Width **1280** & height **720**
I have use this frame of video & display correctly in flutter development.